# increasing speed of app in weak internet connection

Tags: android

I am new to this forum.

We have launched our app yesterday. when i access it in normal signal(mobile), my app works fast. However when the mobile signal is weak, my app works slow and sometimes requests are getting time out because of this issue.

I have a big virtual server( 8 core CPU and 16 GB RAM).

Is there a way to increase the speed of my app when the internet connection is weak?

Thanks,
Hasnu

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, As per guideline: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/tour).

Comment: if your app completly depends on dyanmic data from server then you cant, But you can save some data in shared preference variable, if you know once you get it will not change frequently

Answer (score 0):

You may want to checkout https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uzboHWX3Kvc&index=4&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9CBxr3BVjPTPoDPLdPIFCE&linkId=18472476.

There isn't a whole lot you can do about the internet connection.  It is what it is.  You can do some things in the app like caching where possible.  Make sure you aren't making unnecessary requests.  And possibly having an altered (less network heavy) experience when a poor connection is detected.  Check out the video, it's interesting.